# ksqldb: ROWTIME criteria and timestamp index

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

If I query a stream using ROWTIME criteria, will ksqldb use broker's timestamp index ?

Sample query:

```
select ROWTIME, eventType from MY_EVENTS where ROWTIME > 1688635908983 limit 10
```

I tried a query with ROWTIME criteria but, have no way of checking if the timestamp index was used.

Explain plan didn't mention anything about using timestamp index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not use the brokers timestamp index.

Depending on your `auto.offset.reset` config, the topic would be consumer either from beginning (or end) and each record would be pushed through the query.